# Dynamically Select range from one Excel column

Tags: excel, powershell

I am trying to dynamically select used range of a column from "U5" of table1, only till the column value ends, as another table starts after few rows of 1st table ends, i dont want to select values from table2 column.
Currently I am using defined range as below:

```bsh
$sheet1.Cells.Item($rc, $rld) = "=SUM(U5:U42)"
```

Excel structure is as below:

Table1:

```
Cl1     Cl2 Cl3 Cl4
Server1 35% 2%  12
Server2 37% 6%  19
Server3 23% 9%  86
```

Table2:

```
Cl1     Cl2 Cl3 Cl4
Server1 35% 2%  12
Server2 37% 6%  19
Server3 23% 9%  86
```

Any suggestion how can i select used column range from table1 only, i.e. cl4 of table1 only using PowerShell.